# Navigation menu not working in React

Tags: reactjs

Please help me to fix this navigation menu.Something here is not working.It has to change the clicked cell after click. I would be very grateful if you show me where is the problem

```
class MenuExample extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {focused: 0};
}

clicked(index){
    this.setState({focused: index});
};

render: {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){
                var style = '';
                if(this.state.focused == index){ style = 'focused'; }
                return <li className={style} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this)}>{m}</li>;
            }) }       
            </ul>

            <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p>
        </div>
    );

}
};

ReactDOM.render(
<MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Just to clarify - is your problem ``clicked``` not working on the on Onclick event?

Comment: one issue is you forgot to bind the map callback method, use arrow function like this: `this.props.items.map((m, index) => {}` check the console it will be throwing error: "can't read property XYZ of undefined".

Comment: yes, my friends. it is actually from here http://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/vfcfndxj/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vfcfndxj
I am rewriting this example with es6 class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a binding issue, you forgot to bind the map callback method, here:

```
this.props.items.map(function(m, index){.....})
```

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain the context, like this:

```
this.props.items.map((m, index) => {.....})
```

Check the working code:

```js
class MenuExample extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { focused: 0 };
  }

  clicked(index){
    this.setState({focused: index});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{ this.props.items.map((m, index) => {
                var style = '';
                if(this.state.focused == index){
                    style = 'focused';
                }
                return <li className={style} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this, index)}>{m}</li>
             }) }   
        </ul>
        <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html{
    font:14px normal Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#626771;
    background-color:#fff;
}

body{
    padding:60px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#eee;
    color:#7B8585;
    
    transition:0.3s;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color:#beecea;
}

ul li.focused{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#41c7c2;
}

p{
    padding-top:15px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/q18djk9z/)